# flutter: download and open file with open_file

Tags: flutter

```
Future<File> _openAttachment(String url, String filename) async {
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    File file = File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes); 
    return file;    
}
```

in the onTap

```
await _openAttachment(url, fileName).then((file) => OpenFile.open(file.path));
```

and I also tried return void for the function, like below:

```
Future<void> _openAttachment(String url, String filename) async {
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    File file = File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes); 
    await OpenFile.open(file.path);    
}

await _openAttachment(url, fileName);
```

No luck to open the file, but I can sure the file is stored in the simulator, just the file cannot open properly.
[image shown in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpUx9.png)

Comment: OpenFile.open tries to open the file from simulator but this is the documentation from path library.
On Android, this uses the getDataDirectory API on the context. Consider using getExternalStorageDirectory instead if data is intended to be visible to the user.
also make sure file is stored like checking data directory from android studio device explorer.